# Restricting users to one "like" or action per item in Django

Tags: django

I looked around and haven't seen anything touching on my question.

I'm new to Django right now and have a "like" button working via an AJAX get request and the button disappears after it's pushed.  But when you refresh the page it reappears.

Right now "likes" is a value within a model called Category class:

```
Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0, unique=False)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I understand what I have to do with things on the template side, but I'm not sure how to manage keeping track on if a user has already liked something.  Do I need to add something into one of my models or is there a better way?

Comment: Show the code of your `like` model, please.

Comment: right now "likes" is a value within a model called Category


`class Category(models.Model):
 name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
 views = models.IntegerField(default=0, unique=False)
 likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
`

Comment: You didn't store any info about the user who liked the `Category`?  And who can like the category - registered users only or anyone?

Comment: Only registered users.  I know for that I can use the login_required decorator

Comment: Then @lego-stormtroopr had answered your question. Check if the user is in `category_item.fans` and hide the button.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you aren't storing the likes of each user, just a raw count of the number of times *anyone* has like the page, which means a user can like it more than once as theres no way to know they have already liked it.

Consider something like this:

```
Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0, unique=False)
    fans = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

Then the number of likes for a page is just `category_item.fans.count()` and you can easily check if a `User` is in the set of `fans` and add or remove them accordingly.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I wasn't too sure how the ManyToMany field works so I ended up making a new model called "UserLikes" and making a new one every time there's a like for UserLike instance that doesn't exist.

```class UserLikes(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)

    timestamp = models.DateField()```